# python searching through dict that contain list of nested dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am looking to pull all the "symbol" from a Dict that looks like this:

```
file_data = json.load(f)

{
  "symbolsList" : [ {
    "symbol" : "SPY",
    "name" : "SPDR S&P 500",
    "price" : 261.56,
    "exchange" : "NYSE Arca"
  }, {
    "symbol" : "CMCSA",
    "name" : "Comcast Corporation Class A Common Stock",
    "price" : 35.49,
    "exchange" : "Nasdaq Global Select"
  }, {
    "symbol" : "KMI",
    "name" : "Kinder Morgan Inc.",
    "price" : 13.27,
    "exchange" : "New York Stock Exchange"
  }
}
```

after looking up I found a way to access certain symbol. but I would like to get all the symbol in a form of list or dict doesn't really matter to me.
this is what I got:

```
print([next(item for item in file_data["symbolsList"] if item["symbol"] == "SPY")])
```

I know that the problem is with the next function I just don't know how to get all the symbols

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
[e['symbol'] for e in d['symbolsList']]
```

output:

```
['SPY', 'CMCSA', 'KMI']
```

---

the same thing using a `for` loop:

```
result = []
for e in d['symbolsList']
    result.append(e['symbol'])
```

Comment: @bikoman57 you are iterating over your list of dicts and "pull" into a new list only the `symbol`, I hope it helps